# Nginx cache lock always causes 500ms delay

Tags: caching, nginx

Nginx cache locked requests(http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_lock) always takes 500ms to respond

> $ab -n 2 -c 2 http://192.168.12.103/test1234
>   access.log:
>   192.168.12.103 - - [12/Sep/2017:02:34:59 -0700] "GET /test1234 HTTP/1.0" 200 12 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" "-" 127.0.0.1:9095 0.002 0.002 MISS
>   192.168.12.103 - - [12/Sep/2017:02:34:59 -0700] "GET /test1234 HTTP/1.0" 200 12 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" "-" - - 0.502 HIT

I know that it buffers to a temp file and copies it to the cache. But 500ms looks large. Anybody knows why?
Any help would be appreciated.

Setup info:

1. [Test upstream server](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e1976ed7cbd8f430d1fc9dc45b355225)
2. cache is located in tmpfs (mount -t tmpfs -o size=512m tmpfs /tmpfs)
3. nginx version: 1.7.2.1

**nginx config**

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log  logs/error.log;
daemon off;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {}
http {
    proxy_cache_path /tmpfs/local_cache keys_zone=local_cache:250m levels=1:2 inactive=8s max_size=1G;
    proxy_temp_path /tmpfs;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                      '$upstream_addr $upstream_response_time $request_time $upstream_cache_status';

    access_log  logs/access.log  main;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9095;
                proxy_cache local_cache;
                proxy_cache_valid 200 2s;
                proxy_cache_lock on;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `proxy_cache_valid 200 2s;` seems too low. Change this to `1m` and see how your tests show up

Comment: the 2 second value doesnt make any difference. Please note that the requests are simultaneous.

Comment: how big is the response? 12 bytes

Comment: This is with a test server which just returns Hello world! 
[test server](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e1976ed7cbd8f430d1fc9dc45b355225)

Comment: Okie will test at my end and get some feedback later

Comment: This seems to be the default behaviour. The cache locked requests are locked by worst case 500ms or the time_out value.
https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,276344,276344#msg-276344

Comment: So what are you setting `proxy_cache_lock_timeout` to now?

Comment: If the upstream response times are stable any value little above the response time, we will avoid the behaviour. 
In this particular case we can set about 5ms and the first request will return in 0-1 ms and the locked requests will return within 5-6ms.

Comment: Thanks, please post it as answer and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the default behaviour. The cache locked requests are locked by worst case 500ms or the time_out value.([source](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,276344,276344#msg-276344))

If the upstream response times are stable, for [cache_lock_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_lock_timeout) any value little above the response time, it will avoid the behaviour. In this particular case we can set about 5ms and the first request will return in 0-1 ms and the locked requests will return within 5-6ms.

Answer (score 0):

It's now 2023 and it's still not possible to change the default value using a parameter. The default value of 500 ms is found in [ngx_http_file_cache.c#L455](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/release-1.25.3/src/http/ngx_http_file_cache.c#L455) and
[ngx_http_file_cache.c#L515](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/release-1.25.3/src/http/ngx_http_file_cache.c#L515).

You can set the required value and compile nginx yourself. Example of nginx compilation with custom cache lock polling delay - [Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/maxm86545/7cdcf8dafb04e045ed87d39929232e0f).